# emacs inf-ruby run ruby buffer with argument?

Tags: ruby, emacs

Im using inf-ruby mode in emacs, I really live it. But anyone know how to run a ruby script with arguments by inf-ruby? for instance, I need to pass argument arg0 and arg1 to test.rb

```
test.rb -arg0 -arg1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: instead of `M-x run-ruby`, call it with a prefix arg like so: `C-u M-x run-ruby`. This will allow you to edit the command line.

The long answer: don't. Instead re-structure your code so that you can test / call all the functionality without relying on parsing the command line arguments. Then do some simple tests from the command line whether your argument parsing works out okay.